# Why CloudFrontUrlSigner is an enum in aws-java-sdk

Tags: java, amazon-cloudfront, aws-java-sdk

Source code of sdk saying that `com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.CloudFrontUrlSigner` is an `enum` type.

Why they did not implement this as a normal java utility class; e.g. `class CloudFrontUrlSigner` with `public static` methods?

is there any major reason for using `enum` or just they designed it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Checking on the source of class you're mentioning seems to indicate that `CloudFrontUrlSigner` is merely a utlity class, exposing a few public static methods. Said methods are public and static, essentially working as utility methods, which accept a few arguments, do some post processing on them and then return something (in this case a `String`).

Thus, as mentioned above the core functionality on this class is essentially a utility helper class. With that in mind, one has to take into account the best practices when creating any utility class. The main revolves around the notion of avoiding inadvertent instantiation of the class in question.

With this in mind assume what actions the developer would need to have taken to ensure this had they had chosen to implement this with a normal class. They would have had to declare the class as `final` (to avoid inheriting), they would have put in place a private constructor and then create all the public methods.

Choosing though to use an `enum` pretty much offers all the above out of the box. You can't inherit from an `enum` nor can you instantiate with `new`.

To sum up, they have chosen this in order to seemingly abide with the best practises of creating a utlity class. Ideally, for me I would go with the same `enum` concept but would rather have a singleton service with the said methods.

Comment: Interesting explanation from you. Using `enum` for utility this way I never thought earlier. Upvoted for explanation.